# Problem in configuring LDAP for my drupal

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, ldap, drupal-modules

I am facing problem in configuring LDAP with my drupal, I installed all needed modules and put settings accordingly. When i am clicking test to run the test in LDAP_integration module of drupal it is showing Authentication with the LDAP server succeeded.

But when i am logging out ant then trying to login with LDAP it is giving error Sorry, unrecognized username or password. Have you forgotten your password?

I ran wireshark to see the trace and it shows that searchrequest is going and searchresdone success but results is 0

What should i do??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some base questions:

- Have you configured the branch for your users correctly in the settings?
- Have you configured the common name correctly?
- Have you configured the email attribute correctly?
- Have you tried a search using a third party tool (I use [LDAP browser](http://www.ldapadministrator.com/download.htm), but you can also use the command line tool [ldapsearch](http://linux.die.net/man/1/ldapsearch)) to see if you can return the user with the above parameters?
- Can you turn on debug on the LDAP server to see the actual query been sent?

Also:

Using LDAP over SSL can be tricky, I would suggest getting it to work over regular LDAP first

Comment: hi i am not using it over SSL  what branch i should configure?? yes i configured common name correctly sAMAccountName i am using for account name , for email i am using eamil attribute i did't tried LDAP browser but used 1 3rd party tool it was working fine i will use ldap browser to see what is wrong I cant do anything on LDAP server it is not in my control

Comment: If you do not know the branch to which your users reside in, then this is a big issue, use the LDAP browser to find the correct branch. If users reside in more than one branch, choose the closest common parent branch as the base. For example you branch might be ou=users,o=organisation